# jQuery: How do I add a class to an element that has been inserted into the DOM via ajax

Tags: jquery

My page makes an ajax call and creates some markup on the page from the results. How do I then add a class to one of these elements. For example:

```
<div id="hiddenresult">
    <div class="page">
        <p><a id="23">Some link</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This markup has been inserted by javascript so when I do:

```
$('#hiddenresult a#23').addClass("myClass");
```

It does nothing.

I want to be able to add a class to the anchor when I click a link on my page. Something like this:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $('#hiddenresult a#23').addClass("myClass");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The id of any dom element should always be unique and must not start with a number. You can just try this to add the class.

```
<div id="hiddenresult">
    <div class="page">
        <p><a id="_23">Some link</a></p>
    </div>
</div>

 $('#_23').addClass("myClass");
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you mean that you have a click handler which is not working for ajax injected elements? Try:

```
$("#hiddenresult").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("myClass");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try , it will work :

```
$('#button').live('click', function() {
   $('#hiddenresult a#23').addClass("myClass");
});
```